# SOAP UI Multiple Request

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soapui

I am new on the SOAP UI tool and on Webservices. I have created a method name `HelloWorld()` and I have added the service?wsdl link in SOAP UI tool. It shows me the method with HellowWorld when I double click on the method a one request only found I need here more than request with using Webservice.

What can I do for that?

http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg152/scaled.php?server=152&filename=99746427.png&res=landing

I found method as in Image 1 want method as on Image2.

Comment: Please provide more information. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? Maybe show the WSDL of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on the method and select *"New request"*.

Comment: Jeddix, Thank you for your user i already do that, furthermore it would be great if you try to answer the related question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120653/web-service-check-in-soap-ui-with-session

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Request and select clone TestStep or press F9 then click OK button, Your request is cloned

Regards,
sa.va3feb