# Web Service check in SOAP UI with Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soapui

I have a simple web-service on .Net 3.5 in which there is a method of HelloWorld() as below

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string HelloWorld() {
    if (Session["Count"] == null) { Session["Count"] = 1; }
    Session["Count"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Count"]) + 1;
    return "Hello World " + Session["Count"];
}
```

which works in ASP.NET web-browser and IIS and returns output `Hello World 1, 2, 3, 4 and soon....` depend on how much page open or refresh.

After some time according to requirement of project i was used SOAPUI tool (for testing of web service).
I create new project in SOAPUI and insert the url of service like 
`http://www.myservices/service.asmx?wsdl`

In SOAPUI there is a method with same name but when i execute it the open every time it creates a new session. means its returns me `Hello World 1, 1, 1, 1` at all the time, not maintain Sessions.

However i need to maintain the session for the testing of service.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiktor Zychla, Thank you for your help finally i find that how do we handle sessions in SOAP UI.

We need to Add Request in testCase, add HTTP Test Request. also check the option of Maintain HTTP session.
Ref: http://beforedikshaforgets.blogspot.com/2011/08/soap-ui-creating-test-case.html

Furthermore according to my understanding there is a bug in SOAPUI 4.0 so i shift my service on SOAOUI 4.5 for maintaining session

Comment: Thank you for your support. It was so difficult to find out from their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining sessions requires cookie support at the client side. Most probably your client has cookies disabled. You can verify that easily with any http debugger like Fiddler, just post two requests and see the response of the first (should set the cookie) and request of the second (should carry the cookie).

Comment: If i am not wrong Fiddler is integrated with browser only, SOAP UI is a standalone application running on same system at which service is running, i think for enable session in SOAP UI we need to check option under SOAP UI.

Comment: Not true about the browser, Fiddler catches much more http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to understand, need a little more help, new in fiddler. should you ever used SOAPUI.
i just ask, don't mind it